# SQL queries not working properly through PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

please do not hate because i have searched far and wide for a cure to my problem here. I am using xampp to run this php code in question. The problem is that the search function works perfectly but for some reason my if statements  varying what order it is sorted by do not. All help is appreciated. All love no hate. Thanks.

```
    <html>
<head>  

<title>SeedBase</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSSstyle.css">

</head>

<body>
<h1 class="logo">SeedBase</h1>

<ul div class="navbar">
    <li><a href="HTMLhome.HTML">Home     |</a></li>
    <li><a href="PHPseeds.php">Seeds     |</a></li>
    <li><a href="HTMLcontact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>


<div class="search">
<form method="POST" action="PHPseeds.php">
    <p>Search SeedBase:<input type="text" name="searchbox" value="seed"></p>
        <p><select name="selector">
        <optgroup label = "Sort By">
            <option value="def" selected>Defult</option>
            <option value="asc" >Quantity Asc</option>
            <option value="desc">Quantity Desc</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select></p>

        <p><input type="submit" name="button" value="GO"></p>
</form>
</div>





<?php
echo "<phpcss>";
include 'db.inc.php';

$row = 0;
$find = $_POST['searchbox'];
$choice = $_POST['selector'];
$output = "";

    if ($find != '') {
        if ($choice="def"){
        $sql =  "SELECT * FROM seeds WHERE  name LIKE '%$find%' OR description LIKE  '%$find%' "; 
        }
        else if ($choice="asc"){
        $sql =  "SELECT * FROM seeds WHERE  name LIKE '%$find%' OR description LIKE  '%$find%' ORDER BY quantity ASC "; 
        }
        else if ($choice="desc"){
        $sql =  "SELECT * FROM seeds WHERE  name LIKE '%$find%' OR description LIKE  '%$find%' ORDER BY quantity DESC "; 
        }
    }

    if ($find == ''){
        if ($choice="Defult"){
        $sql =  "SELECT * FROM seeds "; 
        }
        else if ($choice="asc"){
        $sql =  "SELECT * FROM seeds WHERE  name LIKE '%$find%' OR description LIKE  '%$find%' ORDER BY quantity ASC "; 
        }
        else if ($choice="desc"){
        $sql =  "SELECT * FROM seeds WHERE  name LIKE '%$find%' OR description LIKE  '%$find%' ORDER BY quantity DESC "; 
        }

    }
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
?>



<div class="DBpic">
<?php
    echo "<table>";
foreach ($result as $row)
{
    $seed = $row['name'];
    $description = $row['description'];
    $quantity = $row['quantity'];
    $image = $row['image'];
    $output ="<tr><tr> $seed <tr> $quantity cases" ;

    echo "<table>";
    echo  '<br><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $row['image'] ) . '" /><br>'. $output;
    echo "</table>";

    }
    echo "</table>";



?>
</div>




<?php
if ($row == 0)
{
echo "nothing could be found for that search term";
}
echo "</phpcss>";
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$choice="def"`, and all the rest of the `if`s. You're assigning, not comparing.

Comment: Also [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Tip"  You should never select *

Comment: @brad what else would you suggest instead of 'select'

Comment: @guyman123 `select`with the specific column names

Comment: Still use select but not select "*" star, meaning do not select ALL columns, just the ones you need.

Answer (score 0):

In second If Condition you have to use `!=`

```
 if ($find != '')
```

Comment: Why? How do you know?

Comment: because in second if also he is using $find which must not be empty

Comment: The second `if` could be done as an `else` as it's building the queries if no conditions have been entered.